# How to check if atleast one checkbox is checked in my jsp?

Tags: javascript, jsp, checkbox

this is the jsp which displays all the details in my funds table and then gives a chekbox for deleting any one.. but now i want to add a javascript to check if atleast one checkbox is checked so that one db call is not wasted...

```
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Deleting Funds</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var checkForm = function(form){
var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0, l = inputs.length; i < l; i++){
    var input = inputs[i];
    if(input.type == "checkbox" && input.checked)
            return true;
    }
    alert('none are checked');
    return false;
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<%
  Enumeration names = request.getParameterNames();
  while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
  String name = (String) names.nextElement();
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(name);
      com.mini.funds.Admin.Delete(sb.toString());
  }

%>
<br>

<div class="navigator">
<a href="index.html">Add</a>
<a id="currenttab" href="delete.jsp">Delete</a>
<a href="update.jsp">Update</a>
</div>

<br> <br> <br>

<form action="deleteFunds.jsp" method="post" onsumbit="return checkForm(this);">
<table>
<tr>
<th>code</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>type</th>
<th>nav</th>
<th>min_holdings</th>
<th>desription</th>
<th>terms</th>
<th>check</th>
</tr> 
<%

 ArrayList<MutualFund> al = com.mini.funds.Admin.GetFunds();
      String id;
  String box = null;
  int num = al.size();
  int i=0;
   while(i<num)
  {
MutualFund  almf = al.get(i);
out.print("<tr>");
      out.print("<td>");
      String code = almf.getMf_code();
      out.print(code);
      out.print("</td>");

      out.print("<td>");
     String x = almf.getMf_name();
      out.print(x);
      out.print("</td>");

      out.print("<td>");
      String y = almf.getMf_type();
     out.print(y);
     out.print("</td>");

     out.print("<td>");
     int a = almf.getNav();
    out.print(a);
    out.print("</td>")
    ;
    out.print("<td>");
     int b = almf.getMf_min_holdings();
   out.print(b);
   out.print("</td>");

       out.print("<td>");
       String z = almf.getMf_description();
      out.print(z);
      out.print("</td>");

      out.print("<td>");
      String l = almf.getMf_TandC();
     out.print(l);
     out.print("</td>");

  out.print("<td>");
  box = "<input name=" + code + " type='checkbox'>";
  out.print(box);
  out.print("</td>");
  out.print("</tr>");
  i++;
 }
%>

</table>

<br>
<input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is loop through all the input tags inside the form, check for ones that are checkboxes and checked. If you find one, submit the form as normal. If you don't find one, cancel submitting the form by returning false.

Example function:

```
var checkForm = function(form){
    var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i = 0, l = inputs.length; i < l; i++){
        var input = inputs[i];
        if(input.type == "checkbox" && input.checked)
            return true;
    }
    alert('none are checked');
    return false;
};
```

And it can be called in the onsubmit of the form:

```
onsumbit="return checkForm(this);"
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QZPYG/

Comment: alert box is not appearing.. this is not working with my code :( :(

Comment: are you sure the checkForm function is being called onsubmit?

Comment: i tried the code above.. but unfortunately no alert box is being displayed if i click on delete without selecting even one checkbox

Comment: did you add `onsubmit="return checkForm(this)"` inside your <form> tag?

Comment: it shows undefined attribute name onsubmit... i think ther is the error

Comment: And the function is defined inside `<script></script>` tags? If that isn't the problem, please post your updated code.

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? The code looks okay to me.

Comment: ther is no error... just that if i click on delete without selecting any then i am not getting alert box